# Rasterio Geotiff Coordinate Translation

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff, rasterio

I have some geotiff files but the coordinates are slightly off.  I want to use rasterio's API (or other python geo API like pygdal) to geometrically translate (shift) the image.  For example, how do I move the image's coordinates 'north' by a single pixel width.

When displayed with a tool like qgis the image should be exactly the same but shifted up a few pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the georeference of a geotiff is a really simple task. I will show how to do it using the `gdal` python module. First, you should have a look at the [GDAL data model](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723070206/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_datamodel.html) with particular focus on the '**affine geotransform**'.

I will assume that your raster is not skewed or rotated, so that your geotransform looks something like

```
gt = (X_topleft, X_resolution, 0, Y_topleft, 0, Y_resolution)
```

With this geotransform, the raster coordinate `(0,0)` has a top-left corner at `(X_topleft, Y_topleft)`.

To shift the raster position, you need to change `X_topleft` and `Y_topleft`.

```
import gdal

# open dataset with update permission
ds = gdal.Open('myraster.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
# get the geotransform as a tuple of 6
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
# unpack geotransform into variables
x_tl, x_res, dx_dy, y_tl, dy_dx, y_res = gt

# compute shift of 1 pixel RIGHT in X direction
shift_x = 1 * x_res
# compute shift of 2 pixels UP in Y direction
# y_res likely negative, because Y decreases with increasing Y index
shift_y = -2 * y_res

# make new geotransform
gt_update = (x_tl + shift_x, x_res, dx_dy, y_tl + shift_y, dy_dx, y_res)
# assign new geotransform to raster
ds.SetGeoTransform(gt_update)
# ensure changes are committed
ds.FlushCache()
ds = None
```

Comment: Thanks!  The gdal library worked beautifully.  I had tried modifying the Affine using a library called rasterio but I ran into issues where the bounding box did not change.  Essentially the middle sections of the image would move correctly but the edges on one side would become black and on the other the pixels would disappear.  Will switch to using this method instead.